# Элемент массива. Терминологическая путаница

Tags: c++, массивы

Всегда думал, что знаю, что такое элемент массива, а теперь не уверен.
Как мы знаем, классический массив фиксированного размера состоит из набора ячеек.
Например:

`int a[10] - массив из 10 ячеек типа int (каждая по sizeof(int) байт)`

Ячейка массива - это область памяти, к которой мы можем обратиться по индексу. Ее положение в массиве поменять нельзя. В каждой ячейке хранится значение (в нашем примере - скалярное).

Вопрос: элемент массива - это синоним ячейки (области памяти) или синоним значения ячейки?
Например, верно ли утверждение: "элементы массива можно поменять местами"?

Интересует ответ вообще и ответ для С++ в частности.

Comment: Сам искал определения в нете и по книжкам. Такое ощущение, что выражение "элемент массива" часто употребляется по обстоятельствам: то как ячейка, то как значение, записанное в ячейку

Comment: Думаю, что теоретически элемент массива - это всё таки область памяти, но в "быту" элементом массива обзывают ещё и сами значения, что в общем, не совсем верно.

Comment: Что-то народ сегодня на философию потянуло.
Собственно чего хотел сказать, в том то и дело, что поменять местами элементы массива нельзя (только значения), так как положение i-го значения вычисляется всегда как offset (sizeof(type)*i) от начала (указатель на которое мы имеем имени переменной).

Comment: Ну, про адрес - это в С и С++. В других языках может быть сделано как угодно =) Но поменять всё равно будет, думаю, нельзя, ну, если только что в интерпретаторе, да и то, пропатчив его предварительно на совершение такой странной операции. =D

Comment: Я не пытался привязаться к языку, вспоминаю свои работы по ассемблеру. Как ни крути, массив - есть последовательность.

Comment: очевидно, вопрос о классических "raw memory"-массивах. я понимаю, что в какой-нить джаве массив может быть реализован, скажем, односвязным списком

Comment: Ну, да, это справедливо для многих компилируемых языков =) В интерпретаторах типа пэхапэ, где есть ассоциативные массивы, да ещё и не строго типизированные... Там всё, думаю, сложнее. Не ковырялся, но, может быть, элементы массива представлены аж структурами с кучей полей - в том числе индексом, типом, названием и т.д. Но это уже оффтоп ^^^"

Comment: Интересный вопрос, снова череп трещит.
В том то и дело, получается, что массив в самом общем случае это один указатель (возможно с количеством элементов).
Т.е. можно рассматривать массивы с разных сторон, и на примере пхп уже вообще не скажешь, что это переменная, а например целый класс с данными.

Comment: Угу, всё так .з. И согласен, что если придерживаться формального определения, "поменять местами элементы" нельзя =)

Comment: Чаще от контекста зависит, когда на экзамене будет задание ´Упорядочить элементы массива´, не думаю, что кто-то начнёт филосовствовать, что вопрос поставлен не верно. А именно так он стоит в большинстве задачников...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

По сути своей, элемент массива - это отдельная переменная. И определение и смысл можно взять для неё:

> Переме́нная — поименованная, либо
> адресуемая иным способом область
> памяти, имя или адрес которой можно
> использовать для осуществления доступа
> к данным, находящимся в переменной (по
> данному адресу).

Вот. То есть формально это область памяти. Ячейка.

Но в разговорном языке это значение наблюдается лишь частично. Видимо, многие (как и я) не делают существенного различия между этими понятиями, а кто-то и не подозревает об оном.

Когда говорят об операциях с массивом как таковым - "создать массив из нескольких элементов", "добавить элемент", "удалить элемент" - можно считать, что имеют в виду операции над ячейками.

Ну, не в том смысле, что их создают или удаляют, а в том, что выделяют или освобождают память. Так как значения там, собственно, роли никакой не играют.

Когда же доходит дело до алгоритмов обработки, то тут уже на первый план выходит значение. И фраза "поменять местами элементы массива" в контексте какого-нибудь алгоритма, например, сортировки или шифрования будет понятна и верна. Или "найти максимальный/минимальный элемент" - тут тоже понятно, что имеется в виду вовсе не их физическое расположение в памяти или индекс. =)

Comment: последние неск абзацев как-то уж очень пространно. но по большому счету пожалуй такой ответ приму, спасибо

Comment: Последние абзацы - мои размышления "на тему". Ответ - это в начале.

Пожалуйста=)

Answer (score 0):

Есть модель - массив и его элементы, а есть реализация: например, в С - это указатели и адресная арифметика. "Поменять местами элементы" - это что-то вроде модели, абстракции, постановка задачи. А присвоение значений в ячейки по определённым адресам - это реализация.

Comment: здесь вопрос был поставлен достаточно конкретно: что означает "элемент" в контексте стандартной реализации, которую я описал

Answer (score 0):

Элементом массива может быть объект..
В случае ассоциативных массивов

```
return 
{ 
 object: 
 {
   name: "First", dest: "Just for fun"
 },

 object_2: 
 { 
  name: "Second", dest: "Just for fun"
 }  
};
```

примерно вот так ))

если думать, что всё относительно, то можно конкретизироваться ))
а не абстрагироваться

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос: элемент массива - это синоним ячейки (области памяти) или синоним значения ячейки? Например, верно ли утверждение: "элементы массива можно поменять местами"?

Массив, в общепринятом понимании, это набор значений (элементов), расположенных в ячейках. Каждая ячейка индексируется. Как правило, индексы мы не трогаем, а работаем с содержимым. Следовательно, утверждение "элементы массива можно поменять местами" - верное, и оно соответствует обмену содержимым "ячеек".

Утверждение "элементы массива можно поменять местами" может (но не обязано) не соответствовать обмену содержимым в том случае, если мы ввели собственные механизмы индексации (а по факту - адресации), например перегрузили оператор []. Это нечастый случай, скорее исключение из правил, которое должно оговариваться.