# Массив: ячейки или элементы?

Tags: java, массивы, терминология

Читаю про массив, хотелось бы спросить:

1. В массиве элементы или ячейки?
2. Чтобы получить значение, которое хранится в определенной ячейке массива ... или чтобы получить значение, которое хранится в определенном элементе массива ...?

Comment: "Ячейка" - это скорее термин электронной таблицы (Excel и иже с ими), и относится он скорее к отображению, а не к структуре хранения. А вот "Элемент" - это уже структурный термин. Так что из указанной пары терминов в массиве всё же элементы.

Answer (score 4):

И то и другое слово используется для обозначения содержимого массива. Разницы никакой, главное чтобы самому понятно было.

Если нужен как можно более официальный термин, то [в спецификации Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html) *переменные* массива называются *компонентами*:

> **Chapter 10. Arrays**
>
> ... An array object contains a number of *variables*. The number of variables may be zero, in which case the array is said to be empty. The variables contained in an array have no names; instead they are referenced by array access expressions that use non-negative integer index values. These variables are called the *components* of the array. ...
>
> **Глава 10. Массивы**
>
> ... Объект массива содержит ряд *переменных*. Количество переменных может быть равно нулю (в этом случае массив считается пустым). Переменные, содержащиеся в массиве, не имеют имен. Вместо этого обращение к неим осуществляется с помощью выражений доступа к массиву, использующих значения индекса, которые представляют собой неотрицательные целые числа. Эти переменные называются *компонентами* массива.

Comment: Новичок и не понимаю, хоть и прочитал информацию, в массиве есть элементы и у каждого элемента есть значение? Или элементы это и есть значения?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Первый вариант. Каждый элемент — переменная, которой может быть присвоено значение. Элемент не может быть значением, т.к. значение элемента может изменяться.

Comment: Получается у нас написано = new {"S", "T", "W"}; Получается 1 элемент со значением S, второй с T и так далее?

Comment: Можно сказать вот выше в примере что первый элемент S, второй T и третий W или правильней будет сказать что первый элемент содержит в себе значение S, второй T и третий W?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Корректнее всего, пожалуй: «компонент с индексом 0 содержит значение "S" и т.д.». Вариант «первый элемент S ...» не так корректен, но допустим в «разговорной» речи, т.к. понятно что имеется ввиду.

Comment: @MikeMclaren а вообще я бы сказал проще «массив содержит строки "S", "T" и "W"». Как правило когда говорят о массиве все понимают какие у него компоненты и как они пронумерованы поэтому произносить это вслух лишний раз не нужно. Поэтому на практике люди меняют понятия местами. Посмотрите, кстати, похожий вопрос про C++: [Элемент массива. Терминологическая путаница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/8848)

Answer (score 1):

Массив - это такая структура данных, в которой все элементы расположены в памяти подряд друг за другом. Поэтому, говоря об элементе массива, можно сказать что это значение элемента в "ячейке" памяти по адресу 0х123... Такое расположение позволяет, например, в С++ пользоваться так называемой адресной арифметикой. Имя массива, по сути, указатель на первый элемент в массиве, или, другими словами, адрес "ячейки", содержащей значение первого элемента массива. Как-то так.